# Tilting a cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I have a cylinder plotted in 3 dimensions how do I go about tilting that cylinder? In what form would the equation for the "tilted" cylinder appear?

As an example, take the cylinder given by the equation x^2 + y^2 = 4. How would I tilt in some direction?

Comment: There are several ways to describe an object. Just so that we know what we're working with: In what form is your original cylinder given?

Comment: Arbitrary rotation of any solid possible if  three Euler rotations in 3D can be applied.

Comment: @Narasimham: for  a cylindre, two angles are enough.

Comment: OK. For a circular cylinder example two angles are enough. Three for an arbitrary section.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you’re talking about a circular cylinder, it’s the set of points that are at a given fixed distance $r$ from a fixed line—the cylinder’s axis. W.l.o.g. we can assume that the axis passes through the origin; if not, we can translate the origin to an arbitrary point on the axis.

Let the unit vector $\mathbf v=(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ indicate the axis direction. (The components of this vector are its *direction cosines*.) We can then apply a [standard formula for point-line distance](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html): $$\Vert \mathbf v\times\mathbf x\rVert^2 = \lVert(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)\times(x,y,z)\rVert^2 = (\beta x-\alpha y)^2 + (\gamma y-\beta z)^2 + (\alpha z-\gamma x)^2 = r^2.$$

It can be convenient to express the axis direction in terms of [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system): denoting by $\theta$ the inclination from vertical and $\varphi$ the azimuth we have, using standard conversion formulas, $$\alpha = \sin\theta\cos\varphi \\ \beta = \sin\theta\sin\varphi \\ \gamma =\cos\theta,$$ which you can then plug into the above equation.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate space around e.g. the axis $y$, using the relations

$$\begin{cases}x'=x\cos\theta-z\sin\theta,\\y'=y,\\z'=x\sin\theta+z\cos\theta.\end{cases}$$

Then the implicit equation is

$$(x\cos\theta-z\sin\theta)^2+y^2=r^2.$$

---

More generally, a quadric is a circular cylindre if the Eigenvalues of the matrix of quadratic coefficients are $0,\lambda,\lambda$.